# How to setup stand alone Junit and Mockito without maven

Tags: java, eclipse, mockito, junit5

I am working with a very old codebase where no build/library management tool such as maven or ant is used. All library is copied in the local lib directory. I found the stand-alone Junit. That I can import the library in my project. I downloaded and put it in the lib and also configure the build path in the eclipse. I can't import Mokito library in my unit test code. I don't know how do I setup mokito as a standalone library in my project. As shown in the picture below. Please let me know how can I setup this:-

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you aim to use junit5, you have to use the `MockitoExtension` instead. However you require at least a 2.x version of mockito for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe an easier way to gather all depencies is to configure a maven project somewhere else (using `eclipse`), then export it as `runnable jar`. Check the option to export all dependencies into a folder.

You will have to change the scopes, because some scopes are ignored (like `test`).

Then copy the folder to your old project and import all of the jars into the classpath. You still need to check for conflicts manually.

---

Or you just mavenize the old codebase instead ;)